# I am trying to use Font Awesome icons with the Roxima theme - some will not upload

Tags: file-upload, icons, wordpress-theming

The theme connects with Font Awesome and I have been very successful with some icons and failed miserably on others. Roxima, which is widget-based has an area to input the icon name, not HTML. So for the puzzle piece, I inout fa-puzzle-piece and it shows on my website. Using the same method, I have tried to add chart-line, hiking, running, funnel-dollar without success. Any help would be appreciated.

I am not a technical wizard but I have been moving along changing my website to this new theme quite nicely until I ran into this glitch.

Thank you for any advice you can share.

Cheers!
Barbara